# Parallelization in C++ using MPI and Armadillo

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, armadillo, openblas

Here is my question: Are openBLAS/LAPACK libraries(under Armadillo library) able  to exploit parallelism under MPI framework?

My concern is that while running program using `mpirun -np 1 executable`,since I am specifically asking OS to run my program using only one processor,I think openBLAS/LAPACK will multiply/add vector/matrices using only one processor rather than other processor sitting idle. Am I restricting openBlas/LAPACK to execute multiple threads on different processors via `-np 1`? How about using different cores available on one processor selected via `-np 1?`

Answer (score 3):

No. OpenBLAS only supports threads. Same for LAPACK.

ScaLAPACK supports LAPACK-like features that exploit MPI.

You can find other questions about parallel linear algebra software on this site for more details.